# Kubectl logs : Authorization error (user=kube-apiserver-kubelet-client, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

Accidentally deleted the role in AWS console that created the cluster in the beginning but now I am able to access the cluster using kubectl get pods command but getting errors while accessing logs for any pod in a cluster.

AWS IAM Role has following permissions
AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy
AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
AmazonEKSVPCResourceController

The user is already added in kube config auth map

Command used

> kubectl logs "podname" -n "cluster_name"

**Error**
**Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Authorization error (user=kube-apiserver-kubelet-client, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)**

Comment: Try eksctl to recover `eksctl create iamidentitymapping --cluster  <clusterName> --region=<region> --arn arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<aws-role-name> --group system:masters --username <aws-username>`, this user should be same who create the cluster

Comment: This just adds users to the config map and doesn't resolve the issue